# how to make a redirect uri in haproxy?

Tags: redirect, haproxy

I use Haproxy version 2.4

I need to redirect https URL

I did it in nginx, but I need it in haproxy

```
https://1.1.1.1/partner/transparent => https://2.2.2.2/my.FrontEnd.ServiceProvider2/partner/transparent

https://1.1.1.1/status => https://2.2.2.2/my.FrontEnd.ServiceProvider2/status
```

Parameters should be passed too

Example

```
https://1.1.1.1/partner/transparent?partner_id=1111&service_id=1111&order_id=111111111&amount=10&phonenumber=111111111&signature=ZyVvUoM7GpzW44HXbi2DG%2bUHNCk=&way=mobile
```

request

```
https://2.2.2.2/my.FrontEnd.ServiceProvider2/partner/transparent?partner_id=1111&service_id=1111&order_id=111111111&amount=12&phonenumber=111111111&signature=ZyVvUoM7GvzW44HXbi2DG%2bUHNCk=&way=mobile
```

how do I make a redirect?

I tried a lot of options, but nothing worked out for me

```
frontend IN
bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/cert.pem
mode http
option httplog

acl host_status path_beg /status

http-request redirect code 301 prefix https://2.2.2.2 if { path_beg /status }
#location /my.FrontEnd.ServiceProvider2/status if { path_beg /status }
#http-request redirect code 301 location http://%[hdr(host)] unless host_status
#http-request set-path %[url,regsub(^/status,/https://2.2.2.2/my.FrontEnd.ServiceProvider/status,)] if { path_beg /status }
#replace-header ^(.*)$ /my.FrontEnd.ServiceProvider2/status
#####
#http-request redirect prefix https://2.2.2.2/partner/transparent code 301 if { hdr(host) -i host_partner }
#http-request redirect code 301 prefix /status if host_status
#
#http-request redirect code 301 prefix https://1.1.1.1/partner/transparent if host_partner acl     host_partner path_beg /partner/transparent
http-request redirect code 301 prefix https://2.2.2.2/my.FrontEnd.ServiceProvider2 if host_partner
#location /my.FrontEnd.ServiceProvider2/partner/transparent if host_partner

use_backend status if host_status
use_backend partner if host_partner


#===========================backend======================#

backend status

mode http
#reqrep ^(.*)$
#option forwardfor
http-request redirect location https://2.2.2.2/my.FrontEnd.ServiceProvider2/status
#http-request redirect code 301 location http://%[hdr(host)]%[url,regsub(^/status,    /my.FrontEnd.ServiceProvider2/status,)] if { path_beg /status }
#http-request replace-value Location ^https://1.1.1.1/status(.*)$ https://2.2.2.2/my.FrontEnd.ServiceProvider2/status\1
#server status 2.2.2.2:443
backend partner
mode http
#option forwardfor
http-request redirect location https://2.2.2.2/my.FrontEnd.ServiceProvider2/partner/transparent
```

Comment: this works but the parameters are not passed  
how do I pass the parameters?  
    `reqrep ^/partner/(.*)$     \3  if host_partner  
     use_backend partner if host_partner  


    backend partner  
           mode http  
           http-request redirect location https://2.2.2.2/my.FrontEnd.ServiceProvider2/partner/transparent`

Comment: it worked for me 
`acl host_status  path_beg /status
http-request redirect code 301 location %[url,regsub(^/status,https://2.2.2.2/my.FrontEnd.ServiceProvider2/status,)] if { path_beg /status }`